# NOT IN condition

Tags: sql-server

I want those records only which are there in table a but not in table b

```
select *
from a
where companyName not in (
    select CompanyName
    from b
    where CompanyName is not null
)
```

But this is not giving expected results

Let me know if there is another way.

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you expect to get for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM a 
LEFT JOIN b ON a.CompanyName = b.CompanyName
WHERE b.CompanyName IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend that you always use `NOT EXISTS` rather than `NOT IN` with subqueries:

```
select *
from a
where not exists (select 1
                  from b
                  where b.CompanyName = a.CompanyName
                 );
```

My guess is that `b` does not have a column called `CompanyName`, which is why you have unexpected behavior.

Comment: i guess you mean to say not exist instead of "not in exists"